# Symfony2 Forms - Cannot add/remove entities from a collection

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I have a form for a "Person" entity that has a collection of "Nicknames".

I have implemented this following the guide in the cookbook (http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html)

When I create a new "Person" I can add "Nicknames" as expected successfully.

Using a similar form I have an edit page.  On the edit page I have set up the front end in the same way as the new page.

On the edit page, I can edit the existing nicknames and the other simple fields successfully.  However, when I submit a new "Nickname" (or try to remove one), it does not work.

I have var_dump()'ed the request object before it is binded to the "Person" and I have var_dump()ed the "Person" object after binding.  The request does have the "Nicknames" collection passed correctly.  However, they are not being binded to the Person at all, despite the fact that everything is the same as the new page.  Further, I can still edit the existing Nicknames so it is working on that front.

I cannot for the life of me figure out why Symfony isn't creating these new Nicknames or adding them to the Person as it should.  I have looked around and searched but everything just confirms that it should be working - but it isn't.

Heres the entry for the Nicknames on the Person form type:

```
->add('nicknames', 'collection', array(
        'type'           => new NicknameType(),
        'allow_add'      => true,
        'allow_delete'   => true,
        'prototype'      => true,
        'by_reference'   => false,
        'required'       => false
))
```

Nickname type only has one field - "nickname" and its a text input.

Any help?  Thanks for reading.

EDIT:

Here is the update action (changed Person to Player):

```
public function updateAction($id, Request $request)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $player = $em->getRepository('SCDBAppBundle:Player')->find($id);

    if (!$player) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Player.');
    }

    $editForm   = $this->createForm(new EditPlayerType(), $player);
    $deleteForm = $this->createGenericIDForm($id);

    $editForm->bindRequest($request);

    if ($editForm->isValid()) {
        $em->persist($player);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('admin_player_edit', array('id' => $id)));
    }

    return array(
        'player'      => $player,
        'edit_form'   => $editForm->createView(),
        'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
    );
}
```

I realize that to actually persist removing nicknames I need to change the code to persist.  I'm not even worried about persistence right now, because the main issue is that after I bind the request to the Player form, the $player object does not contain the updated Nicknames collection.

Comment: PLease post the relevant code for your problem, the edit action any custom code referenced from there.

Comment: Added the updateAction.  Please let me know if you need any more info.  It's all pretty standard symfony2 code, not much custom work. Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide doctrine table conf (yaml or annotation) ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using Symfony master but 2.0.x, beware, because the "collection" type is buggy there. If you are using Symfony master however, make sure to include a recent version of Doctrine (2.2.3 or 2.1.7) because there two bugs have been fixed that affect the correct working of the "collection" type.

Comment: This issue above doesn't hit a bug of symfony. It's a logic error because the wrong data was persisted...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to use `NicknameType::class` instead of new `NicknameType()`.

And I suggest to add `cascade: [ persist ]` conf attribute to your entity.

Answer (score -1):

You have to get the data from the request with:

```
$objPerson = $editForm->getData();
$em->persist($objPerson);
$em->flush();
```

Otherwise you update the old object without changes from the form.

Short: You have only updated the object which was loaded from the database before.

Comment: There is no need to explicitly persist objects that were already constructed by doctrine. This question was about the forms binding to the object correctly.  The newer versions of Symfony and the Form component handle this much more elegantly now, so this question is pretty much obsolete.